# Создайте функцию, которая на вход получает строку и заменяет в ней все буквы на символ "*". А затем выводит полученную строку

Tags: python, функции, replace

Подскажите пожалуйста, что в функции не корректно?  А, так же буквы/цифры/знаки препинания нужно оставить без изменения.

```
  def my_fun(s="Машинное обучение"):
      sl =""
      i =0
      for i in s:
          if s == 'Mашинное обучение':
              s = "*"
              i += 1
              sl+=s
      
          print(sl)
          print(i)
  my_fun()
```

Comment: что в функции не корректно? - есть ощущение, что всё

Comment: Создайте функцию, которая на вход получает строку и заменяет в ней все буквы на символ "*". А затем выводит полученную строку.))

Comment: Тогда действительно "все не то" в функции. Это задача на регулярное выражение. Без текста задания об этом вообще было не догадаться.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не сформулировали, что функция хочет делать, так что ответ относительно предполагаемого желания иметь вывод каждой буквы на новой строке с пробельными строками для любого слова и строками со *, если на входе нет ничего.

Детальный разбор см.в комментариях ниже.

```
# Исправлены отступы относительно первоначального кода в вопросе, иначе не работает
# Кавычки и апостроф - разные знаки, в условии равенства не будет   
def my_fun(s="Машинное обучение"):
    sl = ""
    # Переменная i не используется в виде int - инициализация и итерация не нужны тогда
    # i = 0
    # Цикл выполняет одно и то же, идя по каждой букве, можно сделать проще, вынеся if из цикла
    for i in s:
        # Код выполняет действия только если на входе ничего нет, в остальных случаях
        # - простая печать буквы и пробела много раз
        if s == 'Mашинное обучение':
            s = "*"
            # Переменная i не используется в виде int - инициализация и итерация не нужны тогда
            #i += 1
            sl += s
        print(sl)
        print(i)

my_fun()
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Comment: txt = "интеллект"
x = txt.replace("интеллект", "*********")

print(x) - Аналогчичный код нужно написать в функции, ч/з def . Чтобы выводилось вместо символов - *, но не затрагивая цифры и знаки препинания.,

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, решения

```
def my_fun(s="Машинное обучение", rep="*"):
ns = list(("").join(s))
for i in range(len(ns)):
    if ns[i].isalpha():
        ns[i] = rep

ns = ("").join(ns)

print(f"Input word {s}")
print(f"Output word {ns}")
return ns

my_fun()
```

Comment: Или так ns1 = ("").join([i.replace(i, "*") for i in s if i.isalpha()])